# How to copy output from a zsh terminal using vi movements(or if that's not possible any other way)?

Tags: linux, bash, terminal, vim, zsh

Currently I am using vi motions in zsh and it is incredible. I work on terminal a lot and it is annoying to switch back to move to copy an output. Is there a way to use vi motions or anything else to be able to go up in the previous shell results and copy them to be used later?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if there's anything specific to `zsh`, but copy mode in GNU `screen` (by default, invoked with `Ctrl-A Esc`) is broadly vi-like, so running `zsh` inside of a `screen` session should give you at least approximately what you want.

Comment: Is that something I can do on mac? I use iTerm terminal but I can use the default terminal that comes with mac too

Answer (score 0):

If what you want is copying a command to be used later:

- ESC K goes back in the history
- when you reach the command which you (partly) want to save:
- yank it to a named buffer, say buffer a, with "ayy or any other suitable vi command like "ayt= which yanks everyting upto the = in buffer a
- when at the command line, you can recall this buffer with
- ESC "ap
- RETURN and your command will be executed.